# firebase serverClientId when building GoogleSignInOptions

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using the google sign-in workflow to get a GoogleSignInAccount object. I want to authenticate google users to my firebase app, which requires a token which can be requested using [requestIdToken(String serverClientId)](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInOptions.Builder#requestIdToken(java.lang.String)) when building my google client api. I'm not sure what to put as my serverClientId?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what [FirebaseUI 0.3 uses to build the sign-in options](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/a934f3b7e3ef51158efaf52c1ef7359811ba5064/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/google/GoogleAuthProvider.java#L73):

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(googleClientId)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

Where `googleClientId` is the client ID as described in the [Firebase documentation for Google authentication](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/google.html). The most important thing to note there is that you need to create a *web application*, despite the fact that you're building an Android app.

**But**: you don't need to specify an id token anymore these days. In FirebaseUI 0.3.1, we'll be switching to [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/google/GoogleAuthProvider.java#L45-L47) for building the sign-in options:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

One less configuration value to worry about. :-)

Comment: Does `requestIdToken(id)` even work? I keep getting a invalid credentials exception. Now I use `GoogleAuthUtil` to get an OAuth token using the email address from the `GoogleSignInResult` as you mentioned above. Is this the right aproach? - You didn't mention `GoogleAuthUtil`...

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an accessToken.

Comment: i tried removing the requestIdToken and still doesnt work. it needs it!

Comment: The firebase documentation still mentions using *requestIdToken()* (visit: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin ). Can we just avoid it?

Answer (score 33):

To avoid `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an accessToken`, use

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
    .requestIdToken(googleClientId)
    .requestEmail()
    .build();
```

[find googleClientId - Here[image: ][1]]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. The Google documentation still references to Google API console, which is deprecated if you work with Firebase...

Comment: This helped me out a lot. I could not find the ClientID anywhere. Works like a charm now, thanks! The screenshot would be worth putting into your answer encase the link ever breaks! @Hoa

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, none of other answers were working.
**Solution:**
**I changed the applicationId because of that it was not working.**
**So make sure you double check if you have changed the application id. register your app again on firebase with new appId and it will work fine.**