# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an accessToken

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to implement google sign in authentication using firebase.
I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ywVw2O1pP8&t=4s) tutorial.

Error log :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1002, result=-1, data=Intent { (has
>   extras) }} to activity
>   {com.clabs.codefosterapp/com.clabs.codefosterapp.SplashActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken or an
>   accessToken.
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3389)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3432)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must specify an idToken
>   or an accessToken.
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential.(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(Unknown
>   Source)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.clabs.codefosterapp.SplashActivity.firebaseAuthWithGoogle(SplashActivity.java:102)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.clabs.codefosterapp.SplashActivity.onActivityResult(SplashActivity.java:91)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5423)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3385)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3432) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1244) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Crashing at following line

```
 AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
```

My code :

```
private void googleSignIn() {
        Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(intent, SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
            } else {

                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Oops! Something Went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount account) {

        AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.getIdToken(), null);
        mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Authentication Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: have you added dependencies? you better follow the official docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin

Comment: Yes i added them.

Comment: please make sure that you have followed every step given in the official docs... and then let me know.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I was reviewing my entire code and I found that i didn't set the requestIdToken while building GoogleSignInOptions.
The correct code is:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                    .requestEmail()
                    .build();
```

Comment: Here is description where you can find web_client_id https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34283355/firebase-serverclientid-when-building-googlesigninoptions

Comment: Yes, we need to pass the web client id to the `requestIdToken()`, and the web client id can be found in the Firebase console -> Authentication -> Sign-in method -> Google -> Web Client ID configuration

Comment: Although we build Android apps, we still need to pass this in to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

You need to get web client Id from your app dashboard in Firebase and paste it here.

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
               .requestIdToken("firebase_web_client_id_for_google")
               .requestEmail()
               .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Initialize Firebase Auth


mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
```

This is the reason why the token is needed to specify

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to add google sign in into Authentication inside Firebase console

[image]

Then you can access the client id like

```
val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
```

if you have the context, or

```
val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
```

Or, take a look at firebase and you will have the token there

[image]

```
val signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestIdToken("paste your id that points to the blue arrow")
        .requestEmail()
        .build()
```